# How to uninstall Anaconda(Mac)

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, uninstallation

I am not familiar to computer.
I want to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it because I accidentally deleted Networkx and some packages included in Anaconda. Therefore I attempted to delete Anaconda and reinstall it however, I got this message `Anaconda is already installed in /Users/myname/anaconda. Use 'conda update anaconda' to update Anaconda.` and could not install when I tried. I used this command to delete :`sudo rm -rf /anaconda` and `rm -rf ~/.continuum/`
 How should I do to delete it and reinstall completely ? It would be very appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-clean
First install anaconda-clean by `conda install anaconda-clean`
and then `anaconda-clean --yes`

Comment: I could made it somehow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install):

To remove all configuration files, run:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Then, open the Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application and remove your entire Anaconda directory, which will have a name such as “anaconda2” or “anaconda3”, by entering the following command: `rm -rf ~/anaconda3` (note the `~` here)

Comment: I could make it somehow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: before the two commands that uninstall the anaconda3, you can use `which anaconda3` to locate the directory. Then `rm -rf ` that directory.