# How can I properly uninstall Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I love Anaconda but it has given me so many headaches that I want to try removing it from my machine and starting over from scratch. The issues stem from paths changing behind the scenes and other things I don't understand. For example, I had to create a virtual environment within Anaconda (`source create`) just to use Spyder. I installed the Quantitative Economics package from home brew (`brew install quantecon`) and it too only works if I create a virtual environment for it. Weird stuff.

My question is: is starting over as simple as

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

and then reinstalling? Or are there other dependencies, possibly hidden, that I should be concerned about? My big concern is accidentally deleting the Mac OS python.

Comment: Hi Invitcus. I understand you're frustrated, but please try to make your title as descriptive as possible, leaving out any unneeded speech. It's the first thing potential answers see, so keep it short 'n sweet. I edited you title to reflect the problem you were having. Please try to keep this in mind in the future. As for your question, have you tried to the top solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990055/how-to-uninstall-anacondamac)?

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDean for the edit. The link tells how to delete it. What I want to know is if there are any potential unintended consequences to deleting Anaconda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [clean a few more files and directories](https://conda.io/docs/install/full.html#os-x-anaconda-install):

> ### OS X Anaconda uninstall
>
> To uninstall Anaconda open a terminal window and remove the entire anaconda install directory: `rm -rf ~/anaconda`. You may also edit `~/.bash_profile` and remove the anaconda directory from your PATH environment variable, and remove the hidden `.condarc` file and `.conda` and `.continuum` directories which may have been created in the home directory with `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`.